# Mapping between 3 entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 entities. GAME, DISCIPLINE and a PLAYER. (and for sake of simplicity lets say they all have id and name properties)

The idea is that:
А GAME can have multiple DISCIPLINEs
А PLAYER can apply for a GAME multiple times if its going to compete in different DISCIPLINEs.
In other words we have ManyToMany relationship between PLAYER and GAME and we have OneToMany relationship between GAME and DISCIPLINE.
What I need is a way to map a PLAYER to a GAME with concrete DISCIPLINE
I am confused how to actually create the entities to have such mapping. What I can imagine for a table to look like is something like that:

```
    game_id |   discipline_id   |   player_id   |
    1       |   1               |   1           |
    1       |   2               |   1           |
    2       |   2               |   2           |
    2       |   3               |   3           |
    2       |   3               |   1           |
```

or what I think would be best is to have this structure in the db:
[image]

But I don't know how to create such entities and how to map them in java

Comment: What does this have to do with spring, this is a basic database question...

Comment: @123 Ah, its a mistake on the tags.. I wanted to just include the JPA, fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "player_games",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_with_discipline"))
    private List<GameDiscipline> gamesWithDiscipline;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "discipline")
public class Discipline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "game_disciplines")
public class GameDiscipline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", nullable = false)
    private Game game;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "discipline_id", nullable = false)
    private Discipline discipline;
}
```

This looks about right. Of course you can make any of the relations bidirectional if you want.

Comment: Maybe from the description I gave it wasn't clear that Many disciplines can be applied to Many games. Because currently the table 'disciplines' has "id", "name" and "game_id" which wouldn't allow adding the same discipline to another game.

Comment: @VasilEmilov Well I guess the part where you said "OneToMany relationship between GAME and DISCIPLINE." led me to believe that it was a one to many relationship and not a many to many one...

Comment: @VasilEmilov I made an edit to the answer to include the new many to many relation.

Comment: I edited the question because your edit still does not satisfy my request. Maybe the visual representation that I added will help on how they should be created on the java side